# app.get('env') usage in localhost and production

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var db_url;
if(app.get('env') == "development"){
 db_url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/localhost';
}else{
 db_url = 'something else';
}
```

`console.log(app.get('env'));`

What does `app.get('env')` in express means? I'm seeing it still print `development` when I deploy my code to live server.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell it you're in production mode; see [part of the Express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#env).

> In development, you typically set environment variables in your interactive shell, for example by using export or your .bash_profile file. But in general you shouldn’t do that on a production server; instead, use your OS’s init system (systemd or Upstart). The next section provides more details about using your init system in general, but setting NODE_ENV is so important for performance (and easy to do), that it’s highlighted here.
>
> With Upstart, use the env keyword in your job file. For example:
>
> ```
> # /etc/init/env.conf
>  env NODE_ENV=production
> ```
>
> For more information, see the Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practices.
>
> With systemd, use the Environment directive in your unit file. For example:
>
> ```
> # /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
> Environment=NODE_ENV=production
> ```
>
> For more information, see Using Environment Variables In systemd Units.
>
> If you are using StrongLoop Process Manager, you can also set the environment variable when you install StrongLoop PM as a service.

You can also set `process.env.NODE_ENV` in a JavaScript file if necessary.